# c# Copy IE's cookie to CookieContainer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies

I currently implementing a desktop application for my ASP.NET website. I am trying to use `WebBrowser` class to allow user to login to the site and then use `WebClient` to make api calls afterward. Based on research and experiment,  `WebBrowser` class and IE share the same cookie (which is good). But I am having a hard time copying the authenticated cookie into `CookieContainer` for my `WebClient`.

I tried to use `Application.GetCookie` which calls `InternetGetCookie` Win32API to get the cookie from IE, the problem is that it does not return the authentication cookie. It only returns cookies set by my site such as Language and User preferences. The cookie should be persistent cookie since I am still logged in after I close and reopen the browser. Any thoughts?

Edit: If `InternetGetCookie` doesn't work, is there anyway I can get the authentication cookie?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN for `InternetGetCookie`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384710(v=vs.85).aspx):

> As noted in HTTP Cookies, InternetGetCookie does not return cookies that the server marked as non-scriptable with the "HttpOnly" attribute in the Set-Cookie header.

If the authentication cookie is not returned, it's probably because it is set with `HttpOnly`. You can check the response headers of the login web request with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it is very helpful. Question has been updated to make it clearer that I am trying to find a solution instead of just why it did not work.

Comment: @Steve, I don't think there's a way to access the cookie via any Windows API if it is HttpOnly.